# Could not execute method for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

I have created a new activity called `BankAccountActivity`. Then I am called the activity from my main activity on a button click using this code.

```
public void AddAccount(View V){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BankAccountActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I am clicked on the button getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you implement the `onClick` method?

Comment: Did you add BankAccountActivity to your manifest file?

Comment: @AramTchekrekjian No

Comment: @AramTchekrekjian Thanks, its working now

Comment: Great, am glad :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please ensure you have added BankAccountActivity activity in manifest

like

```
<activity android:name=".BankAccountActivity" />
```